# Application freezes on loading more items to recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

my Application freezes while loading more items to recyclerview ,my RequestItem class code is blow

```
public class RequestItems extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> implements EventsRecyclerView.ClickListenner {
    Context context;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    List<ParseObject> parseObjects;
    List<FeedItem> feedItems = new ArrayList<>();
    EventsRecyclerView eventsRecyclerView;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    int skip = 0;
    public int remove = 0;
    int isScrolled=0;
    Handler handler = new Handler();


    RequestItems(Context context, RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        this.context = context;
        this.recyclerView = recyclerView;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading");
        progressDialog.show();
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        eventsRecyclerView = null;
        Loadmore(eventsRecyclerView);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        final EventsRecyclerView eventsRecyclerView = new EventsRecyclerView(context, feedItems);
        int spacingInPixels = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.spacing2);
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new SpacesItemDecoration(spacingInPixels));
        LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
        recyclerView.hasFixedSize();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(eventsRecyclerView);
        recyclerView.setOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
                if (isScrolled==0){
                    if (newState == recyclerView.getChildCount()) {
                        skip = skip + 5;
                        remove = 1;
                        feedItems.add(null);
                        eventsRecyclerView.notifyItemInserted(feedItems.size());

                        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Loadmore(eventsRecyclerView);

                            }
                        }, 500);

                    }
                }



            }
        });
        eventsRecyclerView.setClickListener(this);


    }

    private void Loadmore(final EventsRecyclerView eventsRecyclerView) {
        if (eventsRecyclerView!=null){
            isScrolled=1;
        }
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Events");
        query.setSkip(skip);
        query.setLimit(5);
        query.orderByDescending("createdAt");
        try {
            parseObjects = query.find();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (!parseObjects.isEmpty()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < parseObjects.size(); i++) {
                final FeedItem item = new FeedItem();
                item.setTitle(parseObjects.get(i).getString("Title"));
                item.setDate(parseObjects.get(i).getString("Date"));
                item.setTime(parseObjects.get(i).getString("Time"));
                item.setVenue(parseObjects.get(i).getString("Venue"));
                item.setLike(parseObjects.get(i).getBoolean("Like"));
                ParseFile file = parseObjects.get(i).getParseFile("EventImage");
                try {
                    byte bytes[] = file.getData();
                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
                    Bitmap bitmap1 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 100, 150, true);
                    item.setEventImage(bitmap1);

                        if (eventsRecyclerView != null) {

                            if (remove == 1) {
                                feedItems.remove(null);
                                eventsRecyclerView.notifyItemRemoved(feedItems.size());
                                remove = 0;
                            }
                            feedItems.add(item);
                            eventsRecyclerView.notifyItemInserted(feedItems.size());
                            isScrolled=0;

                        } else {
                            feedItems.add(item);

                        }



                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }


        } else {
            feedItems.remove(null);
            eventsRecyclerView.notifyItemRemoved(feedItems.size());
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void itemClicked(View view, int position) {

    }

}
```

i am not able to understand what is happening ,what is problem in this code due to which my app freezes while loading more items to recyclerview